# How to recover data after a failed Ubuntu update from 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2, kernel, 15.04, shutdown

I tried to update Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 but after the update it shows something in error, then I was trying to restart/shut down, but it doesn't restart/shut down. Then I shut down my laptop forcefully through switch button. After, again, I switch ON my laptop and try to open Ubuntu from grub but it shows: ""Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found."" What should I do? Please tell me ASAP. its IMP.

Comment: There is no supported way to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.05. Many people do that for some reason. That can break your system. So it did break it.

Comment: then what should i do to recover my data?

Comment: The data is not lost. It the OS problem. You can boot from another OS.

Comment: How? please tell me the procedure i am new in linux environment.

Comment: I wrote that already in my answer.

Comment: I want procedure of how to boot from another OS. please send me an email on adwardpulkitgut@gmail.com

Comment: You do it the same way as you installed Ubuntu. Just boot from the installation USB or disk and choose "Try Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always boot with an Ubuntu LiveUSB, start the file manager with `sudo -H nautilus` and copy your important data to some external media.

Comment: I tried it But some files are not copied because of "permission-denied" issue. is any other way?

Comment: You can use `sudo` to solve the permission issue. Run `sudo nautilus`. The broken system will not be broken more with that.